# Maven is it possible to use sources jar as depdency in a maven project

Tags: java, maven, jar

I would like to add a source jar to a gwt project using maven.

I tried to do it this way (it's just a poc for managing source dependencies)

source jar pom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<parent>
    <artifactId>test-source-dependencies</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.niflheimcorp</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>test-source-jar</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>attach-sources</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar-no-fork</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
</project>
```

using jar pom :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.niflheimcorp</groupId>
<artifactId>test-utilisateur-jar</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.niflheimcorp</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-source-jar</artifactId>
        <classifier>source</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 
</project>
```

when launching mvn clean install i got the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test-utilisateur-jar: Could not resolv
e dependencies for project com.niflheimcorp:test-utilisateur-jar:jar:1.0-SNAPSHO
T: Could not find artifact com.niflheimcorp:test-source-jar:jar:source:1.0-SNAPS
HOT -> [Help 1]
```

But the artifact is installed by maven just at the precedent step

```
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\CRSD2193\psf\G4R0C3_portaFixe\test-sources-dependenci
```

es\test-source-jar\target\test-source-jar-1.0-sources.jar to C:\Users\CRSD2193.
m2\repository\com\niflheimcorp\test-source-jar\1.0\test-source-jar-1.0-sources.j
ar

I can't see a reason for the error unless we can't declare a source jar as a build deps.

Regards

Nemesis

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: First of all, sources as dependency seems weird. Next, the classifier is called `sources` not `source`.

Comment: Classifier should be `sources`, with an `s`.

Comment: well i want to do this because gwt needs sources to compile and i hate copiing sources in the project webapp (code duplication + weird exclusion for compile and sonar analyze) so in this context source jar as dependency is not as weird as it seems to be. And thank you to point me to my mistake effectively i made a typo on the classifier and didn't notices it :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dumb typo on the classifier sources (forgot the s at the end :-/ ).